# Stop Apache server on Mac High Sierra

Tags: apache, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to stop apache server on my macbook.
I've tried the following

```
$ sudo apachectl stop
```

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

try `sudo  killall httpd && sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`   it's worked on my machine

Comment: This works for me. 
 I want to know if these commands also prevent the service for starting upon boot? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo killall httpd
```

This should work.

Comment: Inmediatly after that command, if I put: `sudo lsof -i :80` I still see the commands running but with another PIDs

Answer (score 4):

`sudo apachectl start`

then

`sudo apachectl stop`

is what worked for me

Comment: If you drop the `t` then it might for you: `apacthectl` → `apachectl`

Comment: if it still not working, do `sudo apachectl stop` again then restart your computer

Comment: or do `sudo apachectl stop` then run `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 3):

see https://superuser.com/a/1110751/925311:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serviceproxy.plist
```

Comment: To add some context for future search indexing: This resolved the issue for me on macOS Mojave after OS X Server was nerfed but somehow refusing to quit despite all the other things I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
sudo apachectl stop 
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

sudo launchctl remove apachectl